# Need help with cleaning files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to clean up some files for a project and need some help. My goal is to go through the file and remove everything after a pattern

my current file looks like this

```
nfr01wrp01:8440:
nfr01wrp01:8441: Server uptime:  19 days 23 hours 58 minutes 5 seconds
Total accesses: 559 - Total Traffic: 15.5 MB
CPU Usage: u124.03 s51.63 cu0 cs0 - .0102% CPU load
.000324 requests/sec - 9 B/second - 28.4 kB/request
nfr01wrp02:8442: Server uptime:  21 days 21 hours 28 minutes 54 seconds
Total accesses: 41 - Total Traffic: 593 kB
CPU Usage: u126.47 s52.63 cu0 cs0 - .00947% CPU load
2.17e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 14.5 kB/request
ngr01wrp01:8443:
kfr01wrp02:8444:
ngr01wrp02:8445: Server uptime:  21 days 21 hours 28 minutes 56 seconds
Total accesses: 43 - Total Traffic: 664 kB
CPU Usage: u144.71 s62.25 cu0 cs0 - .0109% CPU load
2.27e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 15.4 kB/request
nfr01wrp02:8446:
```

My desired output would be

```
nfr01wrp01:8441: Server uptime:  19 days 23 hours 58 minutes 5 seconds
Total accesses: 559 - Total Traffic: 15.5 MB
CPU Usage: u124.03 s51.63 cu0 cs0 - .0102% CPU load
.000324 requests/sec - 9 B/second - 28.4 kB/request
nfr01wrp02:8442: Server uptime:  21 days 21 hours 28 minutes 54 seconds
Total accesses: 41 - Total Traffic: 593 kB
CPU Usage: u126.47 s52.63 cu0 cs0 - .00947% CPU load
2.17e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 14.5 kB/request
ngr01wrp02:8445: Server uptime:  21 days 21 hours 28 minutes 56 seconds
Total accesses: 43 - Total Traffic: 664 kB
CPU Usage: u144.71 s62.25 cu0 cs0 - .0109% CPU load
2.27e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 15.4 kB/request
```

So I need to remove any line that does not have anything after the second : .

I have tried the following

```
grep -o '*wrp0*:*:' clean.tmp > clean.out  - this deleted everything
grep -v '^$' clean.tmp > clean.out - this deleted blank lines only
```

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: investigate regex greedy and lazy matching ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions

Comment: Why are the lines with `CPU usage` or `requests/sec` in the desired output if you require a second `:`?

Comment: It *looks* like you want to inverse-match lines that end in a trailing `:` i.e. either `grep -v ':$'` or `awk -F: '$NF != ""'`

Comment: If two colons are required then perhaps `sed '/.\+:.\+:$/d'`. Assumes gnu sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ grep -vE ':.+:$' input.txt   
nfr01wrp01:8441: Server uptime:  19 days 23 hours 58 minutes 5 seconds
Total accesses: 559 - Total Traffic: 15.5 MB
CPU Usage: u124.03 s51.63 cu0 cs0 - .0102% CPU load
.000324 requests/sec - 9 B/second - 28.4 kB/request
nfr01wrp02:8442: Server uptime:  21 days 21 hours 28 minutes 54 seconds
Total accesses: 41 - Total Traffic: 593 kB
CPU Usage: u126.47 s52.63 cu0 cs0 - .00947% CPU load
2.17e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 14.5 kB/request
ngr01wrp02:8445: Server uptime:  21 days 21 hours 28 minutes 56 seconds
Total accesses: 43 - Total Traffic: 664 kB
CPU Usage: u144.71 s62.25 cu0 cs0 - .0109% CPU load
2.27e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 15.4 kB/request
```

This outputs all lines which **don't** match the pattern `:.+:$` (a colon, one-or-more of any character, another colon, then end-of-line marker'.  The output **exactly** matches your sample desired output (tested with `diff` and `cmp`)

Using `+` in a regex to mean *one-or-more* requires Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax, so grep's `-E` option is used. Note that **some** (e.g. GNU grep), but not all versions of grep, allow `+` to be escaped with `\` to have that meaning - `grep -v ':.\+:$'` would also work in that case.

Comment: Thank you. This resolved my issue. I am grateful for the assistance.